# iOS7 UIView Controller - half way overlapping slave over master controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, segue

I am new in Objective C development. I am trying to develop an app that has one main controller and few other controllers such as registration, login and status screens/controllers. By using regular segue transitions I am able to easily transit to the controllers. However, my problem is that I would like to make the other controllers showing only half way just like when we swipe from bottom up and we get the tools menu, something similar. Can anyone help me with this? Is this possible at all, having half way overlapping View controller?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible at all, having half way overlapping View controller?

Yes, it's possible. You need to look into [view controller containment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html). You can create a "container" view controller similar to UINavigationController or UITabBarController that manages other view controllers.

The kind of thing you're talking about is pretty common, and if you look around you'll likely find some existing classes that will let you do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I just figured this out. Now my next thing is to make it show from the bottom half not from top one.